# Number of Independent variables in su(2) (Lie algebra) is 3, and in SU(2) (Lie group) it is 4...?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

The lie algebra su(2) is the linear combination of the pauli matrices. For instance : $x \sigma_x+y\sigma_y+z\sigma_z$. There are three degrees of freedom, namely x,y,z.

Let us compare it to the SU(2) group.

The definition of the SU(2) group is :

$$
SU(2):=\left\{ \pmatrix{\alpha & - \overline{\beta} \\ \beta &\overline{\alpha} } : \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{C}, |\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1 \right\}
$$

where $\alpha=a+ib$ and $\beta = c+id$. So the SU(2) has 4 degrees of freedom.

---

The algebra is connected to the group by the map $\exp^{ i su(2)} =  SU(2)$

---

How can a lie algebra with 3 independent variables generate a group with 4 independent variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition $|\alpha|^2 +|\beta|^2=1$ reduce the degree of freedom by 1.